# The VSCode debug on the Ec2 machine is falling with a KeyError

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2, vscode-debugger

When running the script in debug mode I instantly get a KeyError with the key b'VIRTUAL_ENV'.
I'm running on AWS ec2 remote machine.
(
It happens even when trying to run the following code:
`print("DONE!")`
)

````
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'VIRTUAL_ENV'
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 666, in __getitem__
    value = self._data[self.encodekey(key)]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_collections_abc.py", line 666, in __contains__
    self[key]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 313, in getsitepackages
    if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ or sys.base_prefix != sys.prefix:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)```
````

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have unchecked "Raised Exceptions" under "Breakpoints" in the "Debug view".